# git issue when add a new local folder as a remote project

Tags: git, git-remote

all,

I have a pretty simple issue, but did not find a good explanation and solution in 10 mins. So I think it is better to ask here. Normally, I follow the rule using web ui to create a remote project and then start my local. But today, I follow the rules below (from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)) to add a local folder as a new remote git project.

```
$git init
$git add .
$git commit -m ...
$git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/group/project
$git remote -v
$git push origin master
```

All went well till the last step. I got an error below:

```
fatal: https://gitlab.com/group/project/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository
```

How can I further check what is going on and how to solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you ran `git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/group/project/info/refs/`. Run `git remote -v` to check if the url is precisely `https://gitlab.com/group/project`. If not, run `git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/group/project` to update the url.

Comment: Thanks. Use set-url to change the url. But got new error: The project you were looking for could not be found. fatal: repository 'gitlab.com/group/project.git/'; not found

Comment: I'm not sure about `group`, but I don't think `project` is the real name of the remote repository. You can browse in your Gitlab web to find out the name of the repository. Let's say the repository is `foo.git` in Gitlab, then the url should be `https://gitlab.com/group/foo` or `https://gitlab.com/group/foo.git`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add valid url to the project that ends with `.git` like

```
https://gitlab.com/group/project.git
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think that is related to .git at the end of the url. I reset the url, now "git push origin master" works. But then got a new error: remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/group/project.git/' not found

Comment: Are you sure that `https://gitlab.com/group/project.git` is actual url?

Comment: Hi, sorry, no, it dose not exist in my git repository yet. I thought it will be created automatically using "git remote add". Then how can I create a valid url from cmd line?

Comment: The command `git remote add` won't create a new repo. First create a repo on GitLab and then use it. To create a new repo use `git init`

Comment: OK, got it. I thought I can add and push the remote repo purely using local cmd, then I see that is impossible. We need to create the new project first in Gitlab. Find a guide talk about it herehttp://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html